# caching lua scripts

Tags: scripting, lua

I have some lua scripts that are used many times. I don't want to use luaL_load every time I change between scripts. For example:

```
load script1
run script1
load script2
run script2
load script1
run script1
```

I want to keep a reference or something to script1 to be able to run it without loading it again. Is this possible? I'm new to lua and maybe this question is stupid... but for me is seems a good optimization to avoid loading a script if it is used often. I want that the above code to be turned in something like this:

```
load script1
load script2

set current script script1
run script1
set current script  script2
run script2
set current script  script1
run script1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, all you need to do is save the compiled chunk that `luaL_loadfile` pushes on the stack. To do this, you can use `lua_pushvalue(L,-1)` to make a copy of the compiled chunk at the top of the stack (because `luaL_ref` will pop it), and `int luaL_ref(L,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)` to get a reference to it in the registry. Whenever you need the chunk you can use `lua_rawgeti(L,LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, refToChunk)`, which will push the chunk back on the stack, ready for `lua_call`ing it.

Comment: After reading this it seems that the refToChunk is a reference to some internal lua structure(the compiled chunk). Is it possible to delete this internal structure? I want to use this to free the memory used by one chunk after I'm done with it

Comment: Sure, I would it would be done with `luaL_unref`. If there are no other references to the chunk, it will be deleted when the GC encounters it. You might be interested in [chapter 17 of PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.html) about weak tables and garbage collection.